# Jboss 7.0 Fails to start in Red Hat

Tags: linux, jboss, redhat, jboss-eap-7

Hi, i'm trying to run Jboss EAP 7.0.0 in  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, the installation goes well until i need to start the service.

```
 sudo service jboss-eap-rhel start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  jboss-eap-rhel.service
Job for jboss-eap-rhel.service failed. See 'systemctl status jboss-eap-rhel.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

After reach for the service log, it shows that the JBoss EAP startup script has failed to start.

localhost.localdomain systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88EAI.png): Failed to start SYSV: JBoss EAP startup script.

```
systemctl status jboss-eap-rhel.service
jboss-eap-rhel.service - SYSV: JBoss EAP startup script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Wed 2017-05-17 05:35:37 EDT; 6min ago
  Process: 16673 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6979

May 17 05:35:06 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: JBoss EAP startup script...
May 17 05:35:06 localhost.localdomain jboss-eap-rhel.sh[16673]: Starting jboss-eap: chown: missing operand after ‘/var/run/jboss-eap’
May 17 05:35:06 localhost.localdomain jboss-eap-rhel.sh[16673]: Try 'chown --help' for more information.
May 17 05:35:37 localhost.localdomain jboss-eap-rhel.sh[16673]: jboss-eap started with errors, please see server log for details
May 17 05:35:37 localhost.localdomain jboss-eap-rhel.sh[16673]: [  OK  ]
May 17 05:35:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/jboss-eap/jboss-eap.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
May 17 05:35:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: JBoss EAP startup script.
May 17 05:35:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit jboss-eap-rhel.service entered failed state.
```

i checked the jboss conf and the eap-rhel.sh looking for something wrong, including the standalone.xml and the standalone-full.xml, but everything looks to be ok.

the files of the jboss are in /usr/share right now (i have installed and unstalled several times in different folders trying to solve it, yes i have deleted remaining files before each installation).

just to be sure, i mention the steps i done after every installation:

1. the jboss-eap.conf was succefully edited. the user and the path of the jboss were changed to the right ones.
2. jboss-eap.conf copied to /etc/default
3. jboss-eap-rhel copied to /etc/init.d

I also opened it using

./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml

it throws this warning:

```
03:56:23,735 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYTX00                                                                                                                                                             13: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is                                                                                                                                                              unique.
```

and doesn't work (because the service is still not active).

¿how can I start the service?

Answer (score 1):

> 03:56:23,735 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it unique.

You dont have to worry about it unless you have enabled JTA. You can set unique value of node identifier in `standalone-full.xml` file like :

> ```
> <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.4">
> <core-environment node-identifier="${jboss.tx.node.id}">
> ...
> ```

Regarding service, please verify steps you have followed http://www.dmartin.es/2014/07/jboss-eap-6-as-rhel-7-service/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **JBoss 7.x**, you can use the following CLI commands:

```
/host=master/server-config=server-one/system-property=jboss.tx.node.id:add(boot-time=true,value=master)

/host={slave-host}/server-config=server-one/system-property=jboss.tx.node.id:add(boot-time=true,value=slave2)

/profile={some-profile}/subsystem=transactions:write-attribute(name=node-identifier,value="${jboss.tx.node.id}")

:reload-servers(blocking=true)
```

This will add the following lines:

> ```
>    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:4.0">
>   <core-environment node-identifier="${jboss.tx.node.id}">
>      <process-id>
>         <uuid/>
>      </process-id>
>   </core-environment>
>   <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
>   <object-store path="tx-object-store" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
>    </subsystem>
> ```

In each profile section of the **domain.xml** configuration file (in domain controller), and:

> ```
>    <servers>
>   <server name="server-one" group="x-server-group" auto-start="true">
>      <system-properties>
>         <property name="jboss.tx.node.id" value="slave1" boot-time="true"/>
>      </system-properties>
>   </server>
>    </servers>
> ```

under each server definition in the **host-slave.xml** configuration file (in host controller).

External references:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/748323
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/260023
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-11208